# Using an ASCII file in mailx

Tags: shell-script, mailx

I have a ASCII file with Unix user names. How can I mail this list to everyone on the list itself? I do not want to use an alias. I was trying to cat the file to a mailx string but it was not working.

Thinking something like `mailx -s "subject" | cat filename`.

Comment: Stupid question: Are you going to use this for spam?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind everyone seeing everyone else's address on the list (which I'm sure is acceptable, given you're emailing the list to everyone), this would do it

```
mailx -s "subject" $(cat filename) < filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like `for user in $(<file); do <file mailx -s 'subject' $user; done` could do, assuming bash.